# Subqueries In The Select Clause

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL and still learning. I am trying to figure out the error code, "1241, Operand should contain 1 column," in my queries below. I just can't figure out what I am missing.

```
SELECT
    o.employeeid,
    lastname, (
        SELECT employeeid, COUNT(*)
        FROM orders
        ) AS allorders, (
        SELECT employeeid, COUNT(*)
        FROM orders 
        WHERE requireddate <= shippeddate
) AS lateorders
FROM employees
JOIN orders o
   USING (employeeid)
GROUP BY o.EmployeeID, LastName
ORDER BY o.EmployeeID;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your queries is that each subquery in the `SELECT` clause should be *scalar* (that is, they should return just one row and one column), which is not the case.

I suspect that you actually want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    employeeid,
    e.lastname, 
    COUNT(*) AS allorders,
    SUM(o.requireddate <= o.shippeddate) AS lateorders
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN orders o USING (employeeid)
GROUP BY employeeID, e.LastName
```

For each employee, this counts the total number of orders, and the number of orders whose required date is not greater than the shipped date.

Comment: The queries that you posted worked it just that on the lateorders column, it included "0". I would just like to return employees who have lateorders?

Answer (score 0):

You *can't* have multiple value return where single value is expected such as:

```
SELECT (SELECT 0 AS Num, 'Hi' AS Str);
```

Instead make use of joins and if not possible get the values separately:

```
SELECT (SELECT 0 AS Num), (SELECT 'Hi' AS Str);
```